# How we create a page on Figma and how we use this app?

Tags: figma

how we create a page on figma using different different icons .and how we add and adjust image on it

how we use different icons on figma and how we create page on it . tell the whole about it and how we post on it and save on it

Answer (score -1):

Click on the team name in the left sidebar.
Select the project you want to create the file in.
Click New in the top-right corner of the toolbar.
Select Design file to create a Figma design file.
Select one file to create a file in Figma.
why we use Figma means it  create scalable type and shapes that look crisp at any size. Figma files can also house bitmap images